# How can I select always the last radio button?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I have a verification page to test by selenium webdriver automation. On the verification page there are always three questions.
But those questions are selected from a pool of questions and so for a single user different questions might appear every separate time he comes to verification page.
So say there are 20 questions in my pool and there are five options (radio answers) for each question, so there are 100 separate radio buttons and each has its separate id/name in DOM.
I am unable to automate this piece of the webpage.
In order to proceed with my testing, I need to always select the last radio button for each of the three questions.

The last radio always contains either "None" or "never" in the label text and radio text label is clickable.
Also the name locator always starts with "1402248" for each radio button.
I am using Page object model in my projet.
Can someone help me to understand how can I identify each radio webelement?

I am using this:

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//*[@class='radio']//a[contains(text(),'never') or contains(text(),'None')]")
protected WebElement oVerifyIdentityFirstAnswer;
```

Comment: Can you share surrounding `HTML` or direct `URL`?

Comment: please share the url

Answer (score 0):

This CSS selector should find all radio buttons that are last of their type inside a parent element

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']:last-of-type"))
```

If your radio buttons are all encapsuled individually, move the last-of-type to that container element:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a:last-of-type" > input[type='radio']))
```

This returns a list of WebElement, which you can iterate over and click every entry. I wouldn't use the @FindBy annotation by the way, since it often leads to staleness exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Xpath to:

```
xpath = "//*[@class='radio']//a[contains(text(),'never') or contains(text(),'None')][last()]"
```